# Find the group $(D,\circ)$ of the symmetries of the circle.

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, general-topology, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

**Question :**

> Find the group $(D,\circ)$ of the symmetries of the circle.

**Discussion :**

I know that the group of the symmetries of the *Sphere* of radius $1$ on $\mathbb R^3$ can be found as :

*You need to find a symmetry to the sphere that when it gets displaced, the distance stays equal. Taking a vector in $\mathbb R^3$ with radius $1$ and letting the sphere be centered at $0$, you need a mathematical definition that will keep the distance intact despite the displacement, as mentioned. In such case, we have $\|v\|= 1$ and we need to find matrices, such that : $\|Av\|=1$ which eventually after a bit leads us to the fact that the group of symmetries of the sphere of radius $1$ is the $3\times3$ orthogonal matrices $O(3)$.*

But I can't seem how to conclude such a fact for the symmetries of the circle (which is something general, since we haven't been given a specific radius). Also, I want an explanation over $(D,\circ)$. Why is that mentioned before the "symmetries of the circle" ?

Comment: It appears $(D, \circ)$ is simply the symbol that your author has chosen to represent this group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symmetries of a circle are the same regardless of what the radius is. Therefore without loss of generality, our circle is the unit circle.

Consider the unit circle in $S^1=\{e^{i\theta}:0\leq \theta <2\pi\}\subset\mathbb{C}$.

All orientation - preserving symmetries of the circle can be described as rotations by an angle $\phi\in\left[0,2\pi\right)$. These rotations are maps
$e^{i\theta} \mapsto e^{i(\theta+\phi)}$ (i.e. $z\mapsto z\cdot e^{i\phi}$).

The group of symmetries of the circle preserving orientation is therefore the group $S^1 \cong\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}\cong SO(2,\mathbb{R})$ (all isomorphic).

If we think about $S^1\subset \mathbb{R}^2$, the matrices of these transformations are of the form
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\cos\phi & -\sin\phi \\
\sin\phi & \cos\phi \\
\end{array}\right)\,.$$

If you do not care about preserving orientation, we can also have reflections with matrices of the form
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\cos\phi & \sin\phi \\
\sin\phi & -\cos\phi \\
\end{array}\right)\,.$$
Therefore, the group of symmetries of an unoriented circle is $$O(2,\mathbb{R})=\left\{\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\cos\phi & -\sin\phi \\
\sin\phi & \cos\phi \\
\end{array}\right):\phi\in\mathbb{R}\right\}\cup\left\{\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\cos\phi & \sin\phi \\
\sin\phi & -\cos\phi \\
\end{array}\right):\phi\in\mathbb{R}\right\}.$$

Comment: What about the $(D,\circ)$ notation ?

Comment: You could take $(D,\circ)=O(2,\mathbb{R})$ where the operation is matrix multiplication, or $S^1$ under multiplication of complex numbers